# How should I create an <a> element node in order to trigger a file download prompt?

Tags: javascript, dom, blob

I am current implementing something along the lines of the following function in javascript to allow for a download of a blob from an API call, passing in the data (blob), the document reference and the name for the file. This works to for desired outcome.

```
saveAs(data: Blob, _document: Document, fileName: string) {
  const anchor = document.createElement('a');
  const downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(data);

   anchor.href = downloadURL;
   anchor.download = fileName;
   anchor.click();
}
```

My questions are:

- Is the the anchor element that is being created exist in the DOM and therefore needs to be removed afterwards aswell? Is there any debt created by creating an method like this automatically downloads using an created anchor tag click method?
- Secondly, does this present any security risk doing it this way if it is (or isn't) direct DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the the anchor element that is being created exist in the DOM and therefore needs to be removed afterwards aswell? Is there any debt created by creating an method like this automatically downloads using an created anchor tag click method?

The answer is **no**. Unless you use `[element].appendChild(anchor)` or use a similar method to add the anchor element to the DOM, that specific element will not appear on the webpage. Your code simply creates an anchor element and clicks on it.

But how can you click on an element that doesn't exist on the webpage? Because from the JavaScript perspective, all elements are actually `HTMLElement` objects. You can do something like `document.getElementById("something").click()` because `document.getElementById` returns an HTML element.

You are basically creating an element that has not been added to the DOM, but it still maintains the same JavaScript properties and functions as all other DOM elements. You are doing this so that you can "trick" the browser into thinking that the user clicked on a download link (less of a hack, more of a workaround).

> Secondly, does this present any security risk doing it this way if it is (or isn't) direct DOM manipulation?

Once again, there is no DOM manipulation going on. The DOM is not being modified in any way. You are just creating a variable and assigning an anchor element to it. Once the function terminates, that variable (and the anchor element) are forgotten forever. It was never added to the page, so it's not a part of the DOM.

As for the security aspect, if this were a security risk, then browsers would not allow you to do this. This is a well-known workaround that many sites use to download files when content is generated from a WebSocket event or HTTP request.